# How to retrieve data from php using json in phonegap?

Tags: php, jquery, json, cordova

This is my sample php code :

```
<?php
    $nai = 18;
    print json_encode($nai);
?>
```

I added these lines in `www.example.com/reply.php`.

I want to get this value in jquery. so that i can use the value to process something.

Is the code right??

```
function connect() {
    alert("chek");
    var term = "nai";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/reply.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: term,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError){
            alert(“no connection”);
        },
        timeout: 60000,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You did not set the content type of the page rendered by PHP.

Comment: should i add anything in config.xml file? where to set the content type of the page rendered by php? any example?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the header of the file that PHP is rendering.

By default html is rendered, use this in your code to fix this problem.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $nai = 18;
    print json_encode($nai);
?>
```

Now this is a readable json format for `phonegap`.

Comment: Where to add this line?? in tat php or html?

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught reference error in that function.
function connect() {
    alert("chek");
    var term = "nai";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/reply.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: term,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError){
            alert(“no connection”);
        },
        timeout: 60000,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}

Comment: any solutions? forgot my code..can you give me some other neat code to retrieve data from php using json in phonegap.?

Comment: Did you try what I did?

Comment: hey thanks... i got the answer.. i think there is some error in  error: function(jqXHR, text_status, strError) this line.. i removed this line..and now its working fine :)