# How to fetch the data from the php using json in phonegap

Tags: php, android, jquery, json, cordova

How to fetch the data from the **php using json in phonegap**, 
On server xampp, I just write the following code **replay.php**. I have taken these example from [this line](http://www.indiageeks.in/phonegap-jquery-ajax-example-jsonjavascript-object-notation-response/) and and I want to mention [this question from stackover flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866100/how-to-retrieve-data-from-php-using-json-in-phonegap), try to make according to it but my android emulator is not resounding, please help me on this topic, I am new in
phonegap and android,

**replay.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$choice =$_POST["button"];
$cars = array("Honde", "BMW" , "Ferrari");
$bikes = array("Ducaite", "Royal Enfield", "Harley Davidson");
if($choice == "cars") print json_encode($cars);
    else 
print json_encode($bikes);
?>
```

In eclipse I write the following code in **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script charset="utf&minus;8" type="text/javascript">
    function connect(e)
    {
        var term= {button:e};
        $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/Experiements/webservices/reply.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:term,
        dataType:'json',
        error:function(jqXHR,text_status,strError){
        alert("no connection");},
        timeout:60000,
        success:function(data){
            $("#result").html("");
                for(var i in data){
                    $("#result").append("<li>"+data[i]+"</li>");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center><b>Bikes or Cars</b></center>
    <center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="cars" /></center>
    <center><input onclick="connect(this.value)" type="button" value="bikes" /></center>
    <center><b>Results</b></center>
    <ul id="result"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see you have added any jquey script

Comment: @AtanuCSE, thanks for reply I just copied from ths http://www.indiageeks.in/phonegap-jquery-ajax-example-jsonjavascript-object-notation-response/, please tell me about it where to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but you are just asking **HOW** to perform this process, correct?  Your question sounds like that code is from a "tutorial" and not your application?  Below is how I have performed this function in one of my own private apps using PhoneGap.

My AJAX call looks like this, minus custom data manipulations:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/myscript.php",    // path to remote script
    dataType: "JSON",                                // data set to retrieve JSON
    success: function (data) {                       // on success, do something...
        // grabbing my JSON data and saving it
        // to localStorage for future use.
        localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

My PHP script functions like so:

```
// PHP headers (at the top)
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

// connect to your database and perform your query    

// then build your output...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output[] = array (
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "firstname" => $row['firstname'],
        "lastname" => $row['lastname']
    );
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

This process above will give you a saved localStorage file of the data from the PHP Script (your database).  You can then use the localStorage to output your data without having to continually perform AJAX requests.

For example:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
var i;

for (i = 0; i < myData.length; i = i + 1) {
   console.log(myData[i].firstname);      // this should output the firstnames.
}
```